# mark end of logical section at kafka when multiple partitions are used

Tags: apache-kafka

I want to share a problem and a solution I used, as I think it may be beneficial for others, if people have any other solutions please share.

I have a table with 1,000,000 rows, which I want to send to kafka, and spread the data between 20 partitions.
I want to notify the consumer when producer reached end of data, I don't want to have direct connection between producer and consumer.

I know kafka is designed as logical endless stream of data, but I still need to mark the end of the specific table.

There was a suggestion to count the number of items per logical section, and send this data (to a metadata topic), so the consumer will be able to count items, and know when the logical section ended.

There are several disadvantages for this approach:

1. As data is spread between partitions, I can tell there are total x items at my logical section, however if there are multiple consumers (one per partition), they'll need to share a counter of consumed messages per logical section. I want to avoid this complexity. Also when consumer is stopped and resumed, it will need to know how many items were already consumed and keep context.
2. Regular producer session guarantees at-least-once delivery, which means I may have duplicated messages. Counting the messages will need to take this into account (and avoid counting duplicated messages).
3. There is also the case where I don't know in advance the number of items per logical session, (I'm also kind of consumer, consuming stream of event and signaled when data ended), so at this case, the producer will also need to have a counter, keep it when stopped and resumed etc. Having several producers will need to share the counter etc. So it adds a lot of complexity to the process.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**

I actually want the last message at each partition indicate it is the last message.

I can do some work in advance, create some random message keys, send messages partitioned by key, and test to which partition each message is directed. As partitioning by keys is deterministic (for given number of partitions), I want to prepare a map of keys and the target partition. For example key: ‘xyz’ is directed to partition #0, key ‘hjk’ is directed to partition #1 etc, and finally have the reversed map, so for partition 0, use key ‘xyz’, for partition 1, use key ‘hjk’ etc.

Now I can send the entire table (except of the last 20 rows) with partition strategy random, so the data is spread between partitions, for almost entire table.
When I come to the last 20 rows, I’ll send them using partition key and I’ll set for each message partition key which will hash the message to a different partition. This way, each one of the 20 partitions will get one of the last 20 messages. For each one of the last 20 messages, I'll set a relevant header which will state it is the last one.

**Solution 2:**
Similar to solution 1, but send the entire table spread to random partitions. Now send 20 metadata messages, which I’ll direct to the 20 partitions using the partition by key strategy (by setting appropriate keys).

**Solution 3:**
Have additional control topic. After the table was sent entirely to the data topic, send a message to the control topic saying table is completed. The consumer will need to test the control topic from time to time, when it gets the 'end of data' message, it will know that if it reached the end of the partition, it actually reached the end of the data for that partition. This solution is less flexible and less recommended, but I wrote it as well.

Comment: Why we can't send each row separately with unique key -- LOGIC_ID_RECORD_ID ?

Comment: Or -- logic section ID, record ID, total records in section ?

Comment: @VasinYuriy l edited the question to explain why counting messages it not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another one solution is to use open source analog of S3 (e.g. [minio.io](https://minio.io/)). Producers can uplod data, send message with link to object storage. Consumers will remove data frome object storage after collecting.